# Deserialize xml using Bond throws System.IO.InvalidDataException : Unexpected node type

Tags: c#, xml, bond

I played a little with [Bond](https://github.com/Microsoft/bond) using this code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using Bond;
using Bond.Protocols;
using NUnit.Framework;

public class Sandbox
{
    [Test]
    public void RoundtripWithSchema()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var source = new WithSchema { Value = 1 };

        using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sb))
        {
            var writer = new SimpleXmlWriter(xmlWriter);
            Serialize.To(writer, source);
        }
        var xml = sb.ToString();
        Console.Write(xml);
        Console.WriteLine();

        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)))
        {
            var reader = new SimpleXmlReader(xmlReader);
            var roundtripped = Deserialize<WithSchema>.From(reader); // System.IO.InvalidDataException : Unexpected node type
            Assert.AreEqual(source.Value, roundtripped.Value);
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void RoundtripUsingSerializerWithSchema()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var source = new WithSchema { Value = 1 };

        using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sb))
        {
            var writer = new SimpleXmlWriter(xmlWriter);
            var serializer = new Serializer<SimpleXmlWriter>(typeof(WithSchema));
            serializer.Serialize(source, writer);
        }
        var xml = sb.ToString();
        Console.Write(xml);
        Console.WriteLine();

        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)))
        {
            var reader = new SimpleXmlReader(xmlReader);
            var serializer = new Deserializer<SimpleXmlReader>(typeof(WithSchema));
            var roundtripped = serializer.Deserialize<WithSchema>(reader); // System.IO.InvalidDataException : Unexpected node type
            Assert.AreEqual(source.Value, roundtripped.Value);
        }
    }
}

[Schema]
public class WithSchema
{
    [Id(0)]
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Both samples output the expected xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<WithSchema>
    <Value>1</Value>
</WithSchema>
```

Both fail when deserializing throwing `System.IO.InvalidDataException` : Unexpected node type

Don't know where to look for the bug really, suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bond `SimpleXmlReader` is having trouble with the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>` line. If you leave this out when serializing, you can deserialize without a problem.

Try something like this

```
using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sb, new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true }))
{
    var writer = new SimpleXmlWriter(xmlWriter);
    Serialize.To(writer, source);
}
```

My guess is that [XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodetype(v=vs.110).aspx) probably needs to be added to the `IgnoredTokens` set in Bond's [SimpleXmlParser](https://github.com/Microsoft/bond/blob/bde70387a56b0e9d4f210020dd9278ca22a34ac6/cs/src/core/expressions/xml/SimpleXmlParser.cs#L45).

Bond versions later than v4.0.1 will have this issue (Bond issue [#112](https://github.com/Microsoft/bond/issues/112) on GitHub) fixed.

Inspiration for this answer came from the [Bond simple_xml sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/bond/blob/ec7e0eb39ba95e827d979a1dc49419f22e820e05/examples/cs/core/simple_xml/program.cs#L23).